# Why does Captain Janeway order the crew to abandon ship in "Year of Hell" if they know the time changes will erase them?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

Why does Captain Janeway order the crew to abandon ship in "Year of Hell" if they know the time changes will erase them?

They are aware of the time manipulations, so assuming the barely functioning ship has the time shield still functioning, they will all likely be erased by abandoning ship.

Comment: The time changes didn't "erase" them, it put them back where they were supposed to be - on an intact Voyager traveling peacefully around Krenim space.

Comment: This is before they destroy the time vessel of the krinians at the end of part 2. They are losing the battle in part 1 and janeway tells the crew to separate and abandon the ship and re-meet on the other side of the alpha quadrant.

Comment: I think you mean on the other side of Krenim space.

Comment: @Alarion, for the record, the exact line is "set your course for the Alpha quadrant".

Answer (score 3):

She did not know. To quote Janeway:

> Janeway: I am setting a course. Janeway to fleet: take your temporal shields offline.
>
> Tuvok: Captain, we wont be protected
>
> Janeway: Exactly. If that ship is destroyed, all of history *MIGHT* be restored.

So, they believed (and were right) that simply leaving the temporal shields does not have an effect, as she switched off the shields and the Voyager continued to crash into the other ship.

Comment: The OP has clarified (in the comments) that this isn't the part of the story they were asking about.

Comment: I might've misunderstood the question. What I understood: why did they leave the time shielding if leaving the shield kills them. My example showed that it doesn't. Should the question have been 'They are not protected', my answer is 'They were able to port temporal shielding to their allies. Therefore, they are able to port it to their shuttles'.

Comment: What I mean is that your answer is about something that happened at the end of Year of Hell, part 2.  The OPs question was about something that happened in Year of Hell, part 1.

Comment: I am only aware of abandoning the ship in 'Year of Hell (2)' around minute 35. When was it in part 1?

Comment: The evacuation of Voyager occurs right at the end of part 1 - we see the escape pods leaving in the final scene.  Only the senior officers remain on board.

Answer (score -1):

The temporal attack on Voyager was held off briefly by Voyager's temporal shielding, during which time Voyager was able to escape.  That means that the temporal incursion was unsuccessful and no time change occured, so once Voyager was out of range (i.e., was too far away for the Kyana Prime to fire on them a second time) they could safely drop the temporal shielding.  It was not necessary for Voyager and its crew to remain temporally shielded indefinitely as you suggest.

Of course, it is true that any individual escape pods that had the bad fortune to encounter the Kyana Prime would be vulnerable to attack from the temporal weapon - but for that matter they would also be extremely vulnerable to conventional weaponry.  They had at least a fighting chance of sneaking out of Krenim space undetected, and Captain Janeway had little choice in the matter, since Voyager was no longer capable of supporting the full crew:

> "Voyager can no longer sustain its crew.  I promised myself that I would never give this order, that I would never break up this family --- but asking you to stay would be asking you to die."

(If in doubt, we can see that leaving the ship did not put the crew in immediate danger on-screen in the final scene from *Year of Hell, Part 1*, which shows the escape pods safely departing Voyager.  In fact, in order to allow the escape pods to leave Voyager must have first had to drop its shields, so had the temporal incursion been successful Voyager would have already ceased to exist by that point!)

Comment: I don't think there's a range of danger for a temporal weapon. If you get erased in the Alpha Quadrant, it would affect you in the Delta Quadrant.

Comment: @Valorum, of course, but Voyager *didn't* get erased.  The weapon itself has a definite range, they have to get up close to a planet or ship in order to erase it, and Voyager was able to outrun them.

Comment: @Valorum, the scene in question is at 42:30 in *Year of Hell, Part 1*.